# how can I find a string similarity degree?

Tags: similarity, word-sense-disambiguation

I am working on keyword extraction system, after the prepossessing, the system extract candidates keywords by checking the text matching with same patterns

Now I want to know how to find the similarity between the extracted candidate keywords senses?
For example let's see the next matrix :

```
     k1   k2   k3

k1   1    ?1   ?2

k2   ?1   1    ?3

k3   ?2   ?3   1


how can I find the values of (?) ??? 
where 
    (?1) refer to the sense similarity degree between (k1) and (k2)
    (?2) refer to the sense similarity degree between (k1) and (k3)
    (?3) refer to the sense similarity degree between (k2) and (k3)
```

note: the keyword can be 1 word or more

Comment: What are you qualifying as similarity ? Differences in length? characters? Number of changes from one word to another ?

Comment: Are you talking about [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: i mean word sense similarity ....
the degree of similarity in meaning

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out WordNet::Similarity - it provides measures of similarity between senses of words as found in WordNet

http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net